# Spring, parsing string to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, xml, spring

I've got model and field like this:

```
@Element(name = "TIMESTAMP")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime date;
```

In response I received:

```
<TIMESTAMP>2016-05-04T13:13:42.000</TIMESTAMP>
```

but during parsing xml to model I have error:

```
 "message": "org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class java.time.LocalDateTime",
```

I also tried with:

```
@Element(name = "TIMESTAMP")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private LocalDateTime date;
```

and this still doesn't work. Any Idea ? I am using `springframework.xml` lib.

Comment: what version of Spring do you have?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE, Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 3):

The problem is by default simplexml lib doesn't know how to serialize/deserialize new Java8 date types.

In order to succeed you need to use custom converter.

Example entity (see the special @Convert annotation)

```
public class Entity {

   @Element(name = "TIMESTAMP")
   @Convert(LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
   private LocalDateTime date;

   // omitted 
}
```

Special converter

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime> {

 public LocalDateTime read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
    String name = node.getValue();
    return LocalDateTime.parse(name, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
 }

 public void write(OutputNode node, LocalDateTime input) {
  String value = input.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
  node.setValue(value);
 }
}
```

Usage

```
        Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
        Persister persister =  new Persister(strategy);
        Entity serializedEntity = persister.read(Entity.class, xmlInputStream);
```

Full source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/zstd/simplexml-java8-dates)